# Reflection.Emit private property access

Tags: c#

I'm using `Reflection.Emit` to generate getters for properties on the fly. So far, my code works in all cases I've tested except where the property isn't public, or is public with a private accessor. The PropertyInfo's are passed in by iterating over the results of GetProperties. When the property isn't public, calling the `delegate` throws

`"System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

I'm using this code to generate: (`property` is a `PropertyInfo`)

```
// Get setter or return null
MethodInfo setMethod = property.GetSetMethod ();
if (setMethod == null)
    return null;

// Method names follow the pattern: "_Set<Property>_"
DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod(String.Concat ("_Set", property.Name, "_"), typeof(void),
                                     new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) },
                                             property.DeclaringType, true);
ILGenerator generator = dm.GetILGenerator ();
generator.Emit (OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
generator.Emit (OpCodes.Castclass, property.DeclaringType);
generator.Emit (OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
    generator.Emit (OpCodes.Castclass, property.PropertyType);
else
    generator.Emit (OpCodes.Unbox_Any, property.PropertyType);

generator.EmitCall (OpCodes.Callvirt, setMethod, null);
generator.Emit (OpCodes.Ret);

return (Action<object, object>)dm.CreateDelegate (typeof(Action<object, object>));
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but you're wanting to generate a getter for a member that has its getter explicitly set to private?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028264/msil-how-do-you-invoke-a-private-method-from-msil which seems to be addressing the same issue.