# Accessing anonymous class via reflection.emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am trying to cast an anonymous class to an interface with a DuckTyping library (https://github.com/deftflux/DuckTyping).

```
public interface IStuff
{
    string Foo { get; }
    int Bar { get; }
}

var asd = new { Foo = "Hiho!" , Bar = 42};
var iAsd = DuckTyping.Cast<IStuff>(asd);
var foo = iAsd.Foo;
var bar = iAsd.Bar;
```

The Library uses a DynamicAssymbly and Reflection.Emit to generate a class on the fly which implements the interface.

Unfortunately, this causes a MethodAccessException, because the anonymous class is private, and a type in a DynamicAssembly can not access private members (unlike a DynamicMethod).
See [MSIL - how do you invoke a private method from MSIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028264/msil-how-do-you-invoke-a-private-method-from-msil)

I tried to

- Create a DynamicMethod, which calls the getter of the anonymous class
- Create a type in a DynamicAssembly, which implements the interface and calls the DynamicMethod.

This caused an InvalidOperationException: "Eine globale Methode oder ein globales Feld kann nicht von einem anderen Modul importiert werden." (a global method or a global field can not be imported from another module.)

What I want:

- Dynamically cast an anonymous class to an interface.
- Do NOT have to manually write a wrapper class, which would defeat the purpose of the anonymous class
- Reflection.Emit sounds great, because of it's low runtime overhead after the type is created.

So my Questions:

- Is there some combination of flags which can be passed to the DynamicAssembly so it skips visibility checks, similar to the DynamicMethod? The linked Question+Answers suggest NO.
- Is there an easy way to call a DynamicMethod from within a DynamicAssembly? That way, the DynamicMethod could call the private member and return the value.
- If no, any other suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You told a story about how you got an exception when you did something. What's your question?

Comment: Perhaps your question is why `callvirt` is used? `callvirt` automatically does a check for null on the receiver. `call` does not. Though in this particular case the null check could be elided because the result of the object creation is never null. The C# compiler will occasionally do so; that it does not in this case might be a minor bug in the optimizer.

Comment: @EricLippert the question is why a MethodAccessException gets thrown, as the IL seems similar to the one generated by the C# compiler and in general, how I can access the member of an anonymous class via reflection.emit. The callvirt was just something i observerved while comparing the two assemblies.

Comment: The method access exception gets thrown **because you're not allowed to access the method**. Why else would a method access exception be thrown?

Comment: Ok, if you say it like that, it makes sense... I kind of overlooked that the anonymous type was declared private. After googling some more, it seems like it is impossible to directly access them. for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028264/msil-how-do-you-invoke-a-private-method-from-msil  As it seems possible to do a similar thing with DynamicMethod, i could try to emit a DynamicMethod which calls the private member, and call that DynamicMethod from my type in the DynamicAssembly... brb, experimenting. And thank you.